# Copied xpath directly from chrome, and not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Trying to scrape odds from fanduel, goal is to get the player's name. In this case Jayson Tatum.

https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/basketball/nba/philadelphia-76ers-@-boston-celtics-31137202?tab=player-points

Even when I copy the xpath directly from chrome it doesnt seem to work. Though it works when I hardcode and look for an element through xpath containing the text Jayson Tatum.
This is my code

```
name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span')))
```

Also tried this

```
name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span')
```

Still get a NoSuchElement trying both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the text *`Jayson Tatum`* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='UNDER']//following::div[1]//span").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='UNDER']//following::div[1]//span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! Very thorough and helpful on my journey!